# Rinohtype/Spinx - How to use python variables in stylesheet

Tags: python-sphinx, rinohtype

I use sphinx to generate HTML and PDF documentation, and was using latex until now to generate PDF, but now looking at swapping for rinohtype.

I'm looking at setting up some custom headers and footers, but would like to include variable text into them, for the version number for example, which comes from a sphinx python plugin. I have rst substitutions, for example `|version|`, that I use in various places in the document, but if I add it to the header via a stylesheet it doesn't get substituted. I also have python variables, for example `version`, in my `conf.py` so I also tried to use `{version}` in my stylesheet, but the builder complains that the variable doesn't exists.

FYI, here is how I tried to define my header :

```
[contents_page]
header_text = '|document_id| |version| |shortdate|' (header)
```

```
[contents_page]
header_text = '{document_id} {version} {shortdate}' (header)
```

Any idea how to get around that issue ?

Thanks

Comment: I’ve learned that the |xxx| construct in RST is not detected by Rinoh. I use |xxx| with raw::html to allow links Sphinx-generated HTML to open in a separate tab. But then Rinoh ignores the |xxx|  and the associated separate links. So I use :: only.. conditional throughout so PDF uses the “standard” `xxx xxx <yyy.html>`_ format of links with Rinoh handles fine. What I am saying is that |xxx| and likely {yyy} (like f-strings) aren’t going to work.

Answer (score 0):

rinohtype does support including reStructuredText substitutions (`|subst|`) in document templates, but this is one of the features that isn't documented yet.

To use substitutions in a page header or footer, you need to include them as follows:

```ini
[contents_page]
header_text = '{UserStrings.document_id} {UserStrings.version} {UserStrings.shortdate}' (header)
```

(Actually, I don't remember why I require the *UserStrings.* prefix. Perhaps there is a good reason for that. If not, that prefix might not be needed in the future.)